# How can a class definition in one cpp be visible/usable to another cpp

Tags: c++, void-pointers

While combining boost, a demo project and another library I ran into problems with my definitions.

Having one X.cpp file, including a class X, I need to use this class for a variable in a Y.cpp, to convert a void pointer as a pointer to this class.

In Code:

```
X.cpp

#include <boost/...>

class x {
}

Main(){
  x c(...);
  handler = init(&c);
  anotherLib-Function(void *handler); 
  //will call function in Y.cpp with c as void pointer
}

Y.cpp

#include ?!!

yfunction(void *c){
  x *cHandle;
  *cHandle = (x *)c;
  (*cHandle).write("texte");
}
```

This is how it worked last time - kind of. I would very much appreciate a solid solution for this messy contruct or anything making this code better/working. Thanks!

Comment: May be you need declare your `x` class in `x.hpp` header file?

Comment: This is exactly why C++ has header files.

Comment: don't have one - had this idea too, but ran into other trouble - already started to refresh my memory on includes and basic constructions, but hoped to take a little shortcut here. I'll try this again and take another look on my trouble on that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the X file in a header file (X.h) containing class declaration and a source file (X.cpp) containing definitions for the class constructors, methods etc.
Now include the header file in the Y.cpp file of yours. Then compile somehow like this:

```
g++ Y.cpp X.cpp
```

Comment: yep, did this, i forgot some importand statements after the includes, that was why it did not work in the first place - thanks to all for reminding me of the right ways ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you only need pointers or references to X, you could also use a forward declaration of class X in `Y.cpp`.